# What are Headers and how to fetch data from REST API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, fetch-api

Whenever I try to fetch data from my REST API using the `fetch` method in React, I get the error:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' .

I've done from research and found it can be solved with headers? The thing is I am new to react and working with API so I'm not quite sure what they are. What might a `componentDidMount` with header look like?

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false
    }
  } 
  componentDidMount() {

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/seniorproject/getUserCourses/1')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: json
          })
      });
  }
  
  render() {
    var {items, isLoaded } = this.state;

    if(!isLoaded) {
      return (
        <div>
          ...Loading
        </div>
      )
    } else {
        return (
          <div className="App">
          Data has been loaded..
          </div>
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow thechans7! Yes, you're right in that CORS can be fixed with headers, but there is nothing you can do from the client side to the headers to fix the problem. You need to include CORS headers in the response from your server.

Comment: CORS can be difficult to understand. I found the following helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

It is not React Issue. You have to solve it on back end side.

Answer (score 0):

Just add headers to the server code. I'll assume it is in nodejs...

```js
    // Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

Another simpler way is to install cors package `npm install cors`
This gives you more flexibility.

Let's say you have a file in public folder`public/data.js`. All you have to do is add cors to the route.

```js
const cors = require('cors');
app.get('/data.json', cors())
```